# use js to control the dom style in phtml

Tags: javascript, php, dom

```
 <div class="alert alert-danger display-hide" role="alert" id="alertTip">
     <?php if($this->flashMessenger()->hasMessages()):?>
           <?php $msgs = $this->flashMessenger()->getMessages();?>
           <?php echo $msgs[0];?>
     <?php endif;?>
     <?php $this->flashMessenger()->clearMessages();?>
 </div>
```

I want to display the alert when hasMessages() return true, so I use the javaScript in if(){}, but it doesn't work
like this

```
<div class="alert alert-danger display-hide" role="alert" id="alertTip">
   <?php if($this->flashMessenger()->hasMessages()):?>
       <?php $msgs = $this->flashMessenger()->getMessages();?>
       <script>function show(){document.getElementById("alertTip").show();};show();</script>
       <?php echo $msgs[0];?>
   <?php endif;?>
   <?php $this->flashMessenger()->clearMessages();?>
</div>
```

is there any way to solve this?
Thank u!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

means to solve this is to change the code sequence
I put the if() in the first row
like this

```
<?php if($this->flashMessenger()->hasMessages()):?>
  <div class="alert alert-danger " role="alert" id="alertTip">
      <?php $msgs = $this->flashMessenger()->getMessages();?>
      <?php echo $msgs[0];?>
  </div>
 <?php endif;?>
<?php $this->flashMessenger()->clearMessages();?>
```

and this solved my problem!